# How do I check package version using apt-get / aptitude?

Tags: apt, package-management, aptitude

Before I install a package, I'd like to know what version I would get.

How do I check the version before installing using `apt-get` or `aptitude` on Debian or Ubuntu?

Answer (score 697, accepted):

**apt-get**

You can run a simulation to see what would happen if you upgrade/install a package:

```
apt-get -s install <package>
```

To see all possible upgrades, run an `upgrade` in verbose mode
and (to be safe) with simulation; press <kbd>n</kbd> to cancel:

```
apt-get -V -s upgrade
```

**apt-cache**

The option `policy` can show the installed and the remote version (install candidate) of a package.

```
apt-cache policy <package>
```

**apt-show-versions**

If installed, shows version information about one or more packages:

```
apt-show-versions <package>
```

Passing the `-u` switch with or without a package name will show only upgradeable packages.

**apt show**

Similar to what is obtained with `dpkg -s <package>`:

```
apt show <package>
```

**aptitude**

The console GUI of `aptitude` can display upgradeable packages with new versions. Open the menu 'Upgradable Packages'. Pressing <kbd>v</kbd> on a package will show more detailed version information.

Or on the command-line:

```
aptitude versions <package>
```

Passing `-V` will show detailed information about versions. 
Again, to be safe, with the simulation switch:

```
aptitude -V -s install <package>
```

Substituting `install <package>` with `upgrade` will show the versions from all upgradeable packages.

Comment: "The program 'apt-show-versions' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing.."

Comment: `apt show <packages>` can also be added to the list

Comment: Upvoted. For anyone looking for a really concrete example, on Ubuntu 22.04, if you run `sudo apt -s install wireshark`, you'll see it will install version `3.6.2-2`. If you [install the Wireshark PPA](https://askubuntu.com/a/778172/327339) with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wireshark-dev/stable` first, however, and then run `sudo apt -s install wireshark`, you'll see it will install version `4.0.6-1`. In this way you can clearly see that the PPA will help you get a much newer version.

Answer (score 82):

Another way using **dpkg** and **grep**:

```
dpkg -s <package> | grep Version
```

Comment: This does not work when <package> is not already installed (which was a requirement in the question).

Comment: better: dpkg -s <package> | grep Version
(Note the capital V)

Comment: The answer already uses a capital V.

Comment: Another option for installed packages: dpkg-query --show <package>

Answer (score 25):

Another option, if you don't know the full name of the package, is formatting aptitude's search output:

```
aptitude search <package> -F "%c %p %d %V"
```

`%c` = status (package installed or not)
`%p` = package's name
`%d` = package's description
`%V` = available package's version

Reference: http://linux.die.net/man/8/aptitude

Answer (score 18):

You can write `apt show <package>`

Comment: `apt` and `apt-cache` do the same thing. If you check the source code, they are both front-ends to the same functionality: for `show`, a function called `ShowPackage` and for `search`, a function called `DoSearch`.

Comment: If you have upgradable packets, `apt-cache policy` will show both installed and candidate versions, where `apt show` will only show candidate version.

Answer (score 16):

To obtain package name:

```
apt-cache search *search term*
```

To get version details:

```
apt-cache show *packagename*
```

I believe `apt-get` and `apt-cache` are being deprecated, with `apt` and `aptitude` becoming the preferred method. Given the longevity of the apt- suite, it's probably a safe bet for some time to come!

Answer (score 5):

To see the latest available package before installing.
Perform update so that you have all the latest package update.

```
$sudo apt-get update
```

Now, To check the latest package available in your repository before installing run below command.

```
$apt-cache show <package name>
```

Example:

```
$apt-cache show latexila
```

or

```
$apt-cache show npm
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 $ rmadison gdm3
 gdm3 | 2.30.5-6squeeze2 | squeeze-security | i386
 gdm3 | 2.30.5-6squeeze5 | squeeze          | i386
 gdm3 | 3.4.1-8          | wheezy           | i386
 gdm3 | 3.14.1-7         | jessie           | i386
 gdm3 | 3.18.0-2         | stretch          | i386
 gdm3 | 3.18.0-2         | sid              | i386
```

from devscripts.deb

Comment: For ubuntu this shows versions found for different ubuntu versions (codenames like "precise", "trusty" and "xenial"). Very slow, but may help you with the decision to upgrade your LTS ;)