# Zenity Windows Too Wide; --width option not working

Tags: linux, debian, zenity

Using **zenity version 3.14.0** and am trying to get insight into how to deal with the problem of the zenity windows being too wide. The problem shows itself when, say, a zenity info box is displaying a long string of text and spaces that have no newlines. This problem did not happen in version **3.4.0**. The zenity window attains a width matching the width of the display before it word wraps. In addition, the `--width` option has no effect, as seen by:

```
zenity --info --width=700 --text="Here is a text string that is so long that the \"--width\" option should have caused it to word wrap, but a \"wmctrl -lG\" command shows that this window has a width of over 1400!"
```

[image]

(If it matters, I get a "**Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.**" squawk when running the above command from a terminal...)

This exact problem was addressed in https://github.com/clue/reactphp-zenity/issues/40, but I could not figure out what was done to fix the problem (inspired by the information in the above link, I downloaded the Debian Jessie source code for the **Zenity** package and grepped the files for the term `setWidth` with no joy...).

***Is there a patch or something available?***

Comment: look 1/2 way down the page where it starts `InfoDialog extends` ... what does that tell you?

Comment: @jsotola You are referring to the link I posted in the OP. Sorry, I'm just an old fighter pilot - can't understand what is being said there, nor do I know what I can do with the information...what file is being referred to?

Comment: it says that the function is `setWidth()`  ... I may be misunderstanding the problem

Comment: Please update the question with the exact zenity command you run and get this problem, so we can try to reproduce it.

Comment: Also, do you require Zenity or are other programs acceptable, such as Gxmessage?

Comment: @thanasisp Good idea! OP so updated...

Comment: @Quasímodo **Zenity** is not _absolutely_ required, but _very_ highly desired - I've been rocking this system since early 2011 and have written tons of scripts that use **Zenity**.

Comment: I don't reproduce this, with zenity 3.26 xfce 4.12 on different OS. it works correctly. Can you [check](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6284/check-package-version-using-apt-get-aptitude) if a newer version of zenity is available into your repositories and if yes, update to it?

Comment: @thanasisp As stated in the OP, I am using version **3.14.0** of **Zenity**. My version of **Xfce4** is **4.10**. The OS is Debian Jessie and a newer version of **Zenity** is not available to me. FWIW, I plan to upgrade to Debian Stretch (**Zenity** version **3.22.0**, **Xfce4** version **4.12**) in about a year or so...

Comment: Perhaps someone who is using Debian (stable) could advise on that, I am on different OS.

Comment: @thanasisp Yes, that would be nice to know. FYI, I am currently rocking Debian 8 (Jessie - oldoldstable).